# How execute BPEL file in intalio?

Tags: web-services, wsdl, bpel, apache-ode

I want execute a BPEL file using Intalio server, have you an idea how can we upload or set this BPEL file in server, or directly in ODE ?

a second question please, i have with this BPEL a wsdl file and i think it's not necessary for upload it with the bpel file and it's used just for call this service from another... is it right what i'm saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intalio BPMS uses a custom deployment component, which interferes with ODE's standard hot-deployment. Although it might be possible to manually deploy a BPEL process bundle to ODE, it is very likely that the Intalio|BPMS deployment component will complain about unknown deployments.

Regarding your second question, a minial BPEL process is accompanied with at least one WSDL (that describes the service interface that the process model exposes) and a deploy.xml (which is the ODE specific deployment descriptor). In case your process is orchestrating 3rd party services, those WSDLs need to be part of the bundle as well.

Comment: The Intalio|BPMS deployment will not complain.